# Black and white film prints are foggy - Nikon FM2

Tags: film, 35mm, black-and-white

I am new to film photography, having adopted my Mum's old Nikon FM2. I've successfully taken photos on this camera recently, but the last roll I received back was totally milky.

I don't know if I had the wrong ISO setting on the camera the whole time - the film was a Kodak T-MAX 400 black and white film - or if things went awry in the processing stage (I took them into a print studio).

I've attached a couple photos for reference, and a picture of one of the associated negatives. I've just loaded the same exact film into my camera again, and I really don't want to waste it. Any advice would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: If the system won't let you post the second image, upload it to somewhere public, imgur etc & post the link into a comment. Someone with the necessary reputation can inline it for you.

Comment: How old was this film? Also, how was it processed? And what was the ISO setting on the camera?

Comment: It would also help to see a posted photo of a negative strip against a light, showing the rebate between frames and the sprocket strips.  That would allow distinguishing between a negative problem (fog, for instance) and a printing problem (contrast set much too low).